# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') style.width="200px"

Tags: javascript

```
win.forEach(e=>{
        if((boxtexts[e[0]].innerText===boxtexts[e[1]].innerText) && (boxtexts[e[1]].innerText===boxtexts[e[2]].innerText) && (boxtexts[e[0]].innerText!=="")){
            document.querySelector('.info').innerText=boxtexts[e[0]].innerText+ " Won";
            isgameover=true
            document.querySelector(".gif").getElementsByClassName("gif")[0].style.width="200px"
        }
    })
```

Please let  me know what wrong with this??

Comment: `document.querySelector(".gif").getElementsByClassName("gif")` - what's this meant to be doing?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".gif")` gets the first element with the class name `gif`.  Then calling `getElementsByClassName` on that element gets all elements that are children of that base element that also have the class name `gif`.  gif within gif?  Are you sure you want _gif-ception_?

Answer (score 0):

Check the nesting. Whether it correct or not. I think there`s no such an element as "document.querySelector(".gif").getElementsByClassName("gif")[0]".
U can console.log it to be sure it exists.

Furthermore, try not 2 querySelector, but try 2 use querySelectorAll if u have multiple items of this class. And after u get the array u can manipulate it choosing the concrete element in [].
Regards.

Answer (score -1):

document.querySelector(".gif").getElementsByClassName("gif")[0] doesn't return any element. Your probably have a typo or something, hard to tell without your HTML code.